# vb.net Scraping from a Website

Tags: regex, vb.net, scrape

**So I'm trying to scrape usernames from a website and followed this Tutorial here**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpAvBOhDrYk 1st part

https://www.youtube.com/watch?src_vid=FpAvBOhDrYk 2nd part

**and Followed everything but couldn't get it to work but this is the vb.net code i used**

1. Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

   Public Class Form1

   ```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://statigr.am/tag/anime")
       Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse

       Dim rs As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

       Dim rssourcecode As String = rs.ReadToEnd

       '<a href="/hannahotaku">hannahotaku</a>

       Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<a href=""/.*"">hannahotaku</a>")
       Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(rssourcecode)


       For Each itemcode As Match In matches
           ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Value.Split("""").GetValue(1))

       Next


   End Sub End Class
   ```

**as you can see im using the website statigram
and the source im trying to scrape is this**

```
<a href="/hannahotaku">hannahotaku</a>
```

**please let me know what im doing wrong as i wanna scrape the
part between**

```
(<a href="/**whatever username here**"></a>)
```

Comment: Try using a lazy version: `"<a href=""/.*?"">hannahotaku</a>"`

Comment: tried and nothing comes up in the list box :/

Comment: I just checked the website you're reading and I find no `hannahotaku` there...?

Comment: thats because it updates every second as i want to scrape every username on the page for the time.

Comment: Okay, I'm making a wild guess at it: try `"<div><div>([^<]+)</div>"` for the regex and in the loop, instead of `itemcode.Value.Split("""").GetValue(1)` use `itemcode.Groups(1).Value`

Comment: alright cool that seemed to work now, but it doesnt let me ctrl+a to copy them all from the list box, how can this be done now?

Comment: Hmm, that I don't know. I know regex, but not VB as much as I want to ^^; That's also another question right? :)

Comment: yes it is, it works now, but just can't copy them from the listbox as i wanted to do this for it :P

Comment: If you use `Console.Writeline(itemcode.Groups(1).Value)`, can you retrieve it somewhere else? Because on top of not being so good with VB, VB's GUI is an even harder task for me ^^;

Comment: idk but i tried using this but can't seem to figure it out yet        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\name\Deskto\scraped.txt", streamRead.ReadToEnd, False)
        Debug.WriteLine("finished")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the whole link:

```
(<a href="\/.+?">hannahotaku<\/a>)
```

If you want to capture the username:

```
<a href="\/(.+?)">hannahotaku<\/a>
```

And from what I can see, it's VB.net would probably be:

```
<a href=""/(.+?)"">hannahotaku</a>
```

Using lazy matching (`+?`) to ensure it only matches as much as required, nothing extra, and the plus sign to make sure there's atleast some one-letter username in there, and it's not completely empty.

P.S. I am not much familiar with vb.net, so if there's some adaptation to be done, please let me know.

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hW0nV7)**

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me still maybe im doing something wrong

Comment: @user3123931 As you can see in the demo, it works. So, perhaps, maybe you need to adapt it to your language.

Comment: can you please add it to the rest of the code just to see if maybe im adding it wrong?, thanks.

Comment: @user3123931 Sorry, but I can't. I am not much familiar with VB.net :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex instead:

```
"<div><div>([^<]+)</div>"
```

And in the for loop, use `itemcode.Groups(1).Value` instead of `itemcode.Value.Split("""").GetValue(1)`. That will give you the parts between the div tags.

To retrieve the matches, try putting them into a file:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://statigr.am/tag/anime")
    Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse

    Dim rs As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

    Dim rssourcecode As String = rs.ReadToEnd

    Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<div><div>([^<]+)</div>")
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(rssourcecode)

    Using Dim addInfo = File.CreateText("c:\Textfile.txt")
        For Each itemcode As Match In matches
            addInfo.WriteLine(itemcode.Groups(1).Value)
        Next
    End Using


End Sub End Class
```

Comment: @user3123931 I looked around a bit and added something to write the results to a file. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: omg thanks it worked, i also found a way to, pretty much just transferred the data from listbox to a richbox but this is better so thank you :)

Comment: @user3123931 Awesome! :D